# PHP loop through array and if key1 add operator to variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have not coded in many years and have decided to make my own golf statistics program.

I have an issue with going through an array and getting the data I want out. I'm guessing it is very simple but I'm very rusty and tried to read myself to this. Thankful for any help.

For the below code I want $dismade to be 8 it now returns 4?

```php
<?php

$score = array(
    "4" => "4",
    "3" => "4",
    "4" => "4"
);

$dismade = 0;

foreach ($score as $stroke => $dis) {
    if($stroke == 4) {
        $dismade = $dis + $dismade;
    }
}
echo $dismade;

?>
```

UPDATE!!

That worked well. Thanks. Now i have another issue where i would need to do this 18 times. I tried doing like below without luck. What i want to do is to check the foreach array 1-18. They will all be the same with 9 keys inside. Am i thinking correctly on this? The below only gets the first position. $row[fp1] for example will always be key 2 but can have alot of values inside which i want to go through and add to $gir and then move on to fp2 and so on to 18 and add into $gir array. I hope my question makes sense.

```
    $hole1 = array();
    $hole2 = array();
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Couldn't select table at!!");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $hole1[$row[rid]] = array($row[s1],$row[p1],$row[gir1],$row[ngir1],$row[fp1],$row[fw1],$row[ud1],$row[ss1],$row[pen1]);
    $hole2[$row[rid]] = array($row[s2],$row[p2],$row[gir2],$row[ngir2],$row[fp2],$row[fw2],$row[ud2],$row[ss2],$row[pen2]);

    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    $gir = array(); 

    foreach (array_combine($hole1,$hole2) as $value)  {
        if($value[2] == 1) {
            array_push($gir,$value[4] );
            }
        }

    print_r ($gir);
```

Comment: You are overwriting key '4' the second time you enter it. What was your intention?

Comment: Obliviously not to override it. Btw, down vote from whom ever wasn't justified.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your `$score` keys. As you can see you have a duplicate key `"4"`.

Try something like:

```
$score = array([4,4], [3,4], [4,4]);
$dismade = 0;
foreach ($score as $value) {
  if($value[0] == 4) {
    $dismade += $value[1];
  }
}
echo $dismade;
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: thanks for the quick help. it worked nicely. would you have gone about this differently?

Comment: It depends on the context - don't know anything about golf ^^. It's okay, I guess

Comment: since im new i can not vote but thanks for the reply and the help!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have an duplicate key "4" in your array, since every key is unique in

array so the third line "4" => "4" will overlap the first line within array.